# Django REST Framework и непонятные запросы в базу данных

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Имеется:

- Django==3.2.9
- djangorestframework==3.12.4
- django-debug-toolbar==3.2.2

При GET запросе на страницу индекс, на которой висит список объектов из БД, через django-debug-toolbar наблюдаю два дополнительных запроса в БД от REST Framework, один запрос получает сессии, второй пользователей. Вопрос такой, можно ли это (запросы) как-то отключить?

**BaseContentManger** 
*(В этом классе получаю qeryset объектов)*

```
class BaseContentManger:
"""Класс упвления контентом"""

    def get_reqiested_objects_list(self, model):
        return model.objects.annotate(num_obj=Count('own_objects')).filter(is_active=True).only('title')
```

---

**Views.py**

```
class IndexView(BaseContentManger, APIView):
    """Класс представления страницы index"""
    model = TestObjCategory

    def get(self, request):
        objects = self.get_reqiested_objects_list(model=self.model)
        serializer = CategoryListSerializer(objects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', api_views.IndexView.as_view(), name='api_index_view'),
]
```

---

**На выходе**
*(127.0.0.1:8000/api/index/)*
[image]

---

**Результат django-debug-toolba**
[image]

---

**ЗЫ**
До использования djangorestframework запрос в БД был один!!!

Спасибо.

Comment: Надпись «admin» в правом верхнем углу намекает, что вы залогинились в свой сайт, соответственно Django ходит в базу проверять действительность логина

Comment: Стыдоба, как я не заметил ((((( Напишите ответ что бы я мог его принять ))